# Measuring CPU time using Scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm new to working with [Scilab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab), and I'm trying to run the code below, but when I try it keeps showing me this error::

```
test3(1000)                    //Line that I type to run the code
 !--error 4                   //First error
Undefined variable: cputime
at line       2 of function test3 called by:
```

I ran it using [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), and it worked, but I can't figure out how to make it run using Scilab.

For sample code when typed using the Scilab editor, see below.

```
function test3(n)
t = cputime;
for (j = 1:n)
    x(j) = sin(j);
end
disp(cputime - t);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typing `help cputime` in the Scilab console will reveal that this is not a Scilab function.  The near-equivalent Scilab  function is `timer()`, but its behavior is a bit different:

- `cputime` in Matlab measures time since Matlab started
- `timer()` measures time since the last call to `timer()`

Here is your function rewritten in Scilab:

```
function test3(n)
    timer()
    for j = 1:n
        x(j) = sin(j)
    end
    disp(timer())
endfunction
```

Note that Scilab functions must end with `endfunction`, and that semicolons are optional: line-by-line output is suppressed in Scilab by default.

For completeness, I'll mention `tic()` and `toc()`, which work just like Matlab's `tic` and `toc`, measuring real-world time of computation.